# jacocoTestCoverageVerification : How gitlab counts test coverage - Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, test-coverage

I have a project where Sprig Boot, JUnit and Gradle are being used. In the Gradle dependency I have found the following lines :

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = Float.parseFloat(System.getenv().getOrDefault("CI_TEST_COVERAGE_REQUIRED", "0.7"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As par me these lines indicating that in the Gitlab the test coverage must the 70% at least.

When I have the run tests with coverage in IntelliJ IDE, I have got 3 measurements, shown in the image.

[image]

So, we have got 3 values, which are different and indicating several types.

So my concern is that how the one single value 70% will be calculated from these 3 values?

Is there any way  or command to get this single 70% or .7 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going through the documentation from [JacocoCoverageVerification](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoCoverageVerification.html#org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoCoverageVerification:violationRules) to [JacocoViolationRule](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/rules/JacocoViolationRule.html) and finally [JacocoLimit#getCounter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/rules/JacocoLimit.html#getCounter--)

> The counter that applies to the limit as defined by org.jacoco.core.analysis.ICoverageNode.CounterEntity. Valid values are INSTRUCTION, LINE, BRANCH, COMPLEXITY, METHOD and CLASS. Defaults to INSTRUCTION.

So the default is `INSTRUCTION`, of course you can specify the value of `counter` as `CLASS`, `METHOD` or `LINE`.

In case you want to know the difference between `LINE` and `INSTRUCTION`, please take a look on [Lines of Code VS Instructions while measuring code quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571414/lines-of-code-vs-instructions-while-measuring-code-quality).